# Python. Get Internal XML with no whitespace

Tags: python, xml, removing-whitespace

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <head>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <project>hello, world</project>
        <date>2020-08-15</date>
    </head>
    <file name="helloworld.py"/>
    <file name="helloworld.ps1"/>
    <file name="helloworld.bat"/>
</data>
```

I need to grab the data in the head element with no white space between the elements, like this:

```
<version>1.0</version><project>hello, world</project><date>2020-08-15</date>
```

And then hash it. Right now, I have to do some string manipulation to get it into one line:

```
root = ET.parse('myfile.xml').getroot()
header = ET.tostring(root[0]).decode('utf-8')
import re
header = re.sub('\n','',header)
header = re.sub('>\s+<','><',header)
header = header.replace('<head>','')
header = header.replace('</head>','')
header = header.strip()
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Powershell XML objects have a simple InnerXML property that gives you the XML within an element with no white space as a String. Does Python have a method that can make this easier?

Answer (score 2):

below (not using any external library - just core python)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('input.xml')
head = root.find('.//head')
combined = ''.join(['<{}>{}</{}>'.format(e.tag,e.text,e.tag) for e in list(head)])
print(combined)
```

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <head>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <project>hello, world</project>
        <date>2020-08-15</date>
    </head>
    <file name="helloworld.py"/>
    <file name="helloworld.ps1"/>
    <file name="helloworld.bat"/>
</data>
```

output

```
<version>1.0</version><project>hello, world</project><date>2020-08-15</date>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use external libraries, BeautifulSoup is great at this.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup

Here is an example with your document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

xml_doc = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data>
 <head>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <project>hello, world</project>
     <date>2020-08-15</date>
 </head>
 <file name="helloworld.py"/>
 <file name="helloworld.ps1"/>
 <file name="helloworld.bat"/>
</data>"""

page_soup = bs(xml_doc)

page_soup.head.getText()

page_soup.head.getText().strip().replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
```

This will return the contents of the children of the head tag, and strip out newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Each method can have problems. Some methods will also delete useful spaces, Some methods become troublesome when the node has attribute. So I'll give you a third way. It may also be an imperfect approach:)

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
# xml_doc = utils.getFileContent('myfile.xml')
xml_doc = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data>
 <head>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <project>hello, world</project>
     <date>2020-08-15</date>
 </head>
 <file name="helloworld.py"/>
 <file name="helloworld.ps1"/>
 <file name="helloworld.bat"/>
</data>"""

doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml_doc)
headXml = doc.head.html.strip() # Get internal data of head
print (doc.replaceReg(headXml,'>[\s]+<','><')) # Replace newlines and spaces with regex
```

Result:

```
<version>1.0</version><project>hello, world</project><date>2020-08-15</date>
```